# MYSQL - How may i subtract two columns on two different rows, on the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a select taht brings the result like this:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| parking_id| start_time |   end_time   |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
|        38 | 09:15:00   | 10:32:00     |
|        57 | 11:45:00   | 13:21:00     |
|        33 | 14:40:00   | 16:35:00     |
|        15 | 17:13:00   | 19:15:00     |
|        68 | 20:54:00   | NULL         |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

As you can see the IDs dont follow a linear order, but wat i really need is a select that brings me the time between the new **start_time** and **end_time for the last inserted** , that follows this non linear order, so i need a select that brings me this:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+----------------+
| parking_id| start_time |   end_time   | time_btw_parks |
+-----------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|        38 | 09:15:00   | 10:32:00     |     NULL       |
|        57 | 11:45:00   | 13:21:00     |   01:13:00     |
|        33 | 14:40:00   | 16:35:00     |   01:19:00     |
|        15 | 17:13:00   | 19:15:00     |   00:38:00     |
|        68 | 20:54:00   | NULL         |   01:39:00     |
+-----------+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Doesn't have to necessary be  select query. Anything that solves it would help.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: You probably want to have a look at [`timediff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff). But what time needs to be "diffed" to what other time remains a mystery to me here. I guess you need to [edit] the question and elaborate on how the result can be calculated from the given data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you can use `timediff()` function:

```
select t.parking_id, t.start_time, t.end_time,
  timediff(t.start_time, max(tt.end_time)) time_btw_parks
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on t.start_time > tt.end_time 
group by t.parking_id, t.start_time, t.end_time
order by t.start_time
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ig9tSKd8BYR8K4F3m22aGo/2).
Results:

```
| parking_id | start_time | end_time | time_btw_parks |
| ---------- | ---------- | -------- | -------------- |
| 38         | 09:15:00   | 10:32:00 |                |
| 57         | 11:45:00   | 13:21:00 | 01:13:00       |
| 33         | 14:40:00   | 16:35:00 | 01:19:00       |
| 15         | 17:13:00   | 19:15:00 | 00:38:00       |
| 68         | 20:54:00   |          | 01:39:00       |
```

Comment: Thanks, thats helped, i wasnt expecting an  answer so fast!, except for the fact thats bringing the right answer but for the wrong ID check fidle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/360cde/3